# How a class that does not initialize its all members in its constructor to be initialized in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

The code is like

```
class C{
       public:
             int m1;
             int m2;
             C(int m);
}
C::C(int m):m1(m){};
int main(){
       C* c = new C(1);
       cout << c->m2 << endl;
}
```

I want to know what value m2 is to be initilized. I think c is value initialized, and m2 is default initialized.

I test it with C++11 and g++4.8.4, and m2 seems always 0. I think 0 is default initializing, but default initializing is not 0. So initializing to 0 can be guaranteed?

Comment: Please, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization -- In your example `m2` is not guaranteed to be initialized to 0. it will be dependent on the compiler and the machine. Most of the time it will be `0`, but again, it is not guaranteed

Comment: Compiling without optimization tend to use 0 as default initialization; `-O2` tends to not use `0` as default initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`c` is [copy initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), and not value initialized. `m2` is in fact default initialized, yes, but that does not mean that its value is always `0` (that would be guaranteed by value and aggregate initialization).

```
int(); // value initialized - always 0
int{}; // value initialized - always 0
int a; // default initialized - indeterminate value

struct X {};
X x{}; // aggregate initialized
```

Comment: `int a();` is a function declaration.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: `int{}` is not aggregate initialization. `int`is not an aggregate. `int{}` is also value initialization. See [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Comment: @Destructor Thanks! Didn't know that types like `int` were not aggregates